# Change Badge Color In JS By Value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend, badge

I'm new in javascript. I try to make the badge color change according to the value. I've tried but the output is error badge

```
<th>
    <select class="select2-placeholder form-control" id="sIsLocked">
        <option value="">Pilih</option>
        <option value="false">Un Locked</option>
        <option value="true">Locked</option>
            
    </select>
</th>


render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
    switch (data) {
        case false:
            return '<span class="badge bg-success">Un Locked</span>';
        case true:
            return '<span class="badge rounded-pill bg-secondary">Locked</span>';
        default:
            return '<span class="badge badge-danger badge-pill">Error!</span>';
            
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `console.log(data)` as the first line in the `render` function to see data's value. It is most likely not `true`/`false` and hence, the `default` case is used.

Comment: I believe you the data value there would be in the string format, you can check as suggested above to console.log the value and data type.

Comment: the true/false is a string here. so you have to check for "true"/"false" rather then the boolean true/false

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is parameter data is not a boolean type. Print the data using console.log() and post it here.